# What is the difference between dojo's .ready and jQuery $(document).ready

Tags: jquery, dojo, document-ready, jquery-events, ready

With my limited knowledge, I thought both dojo's  `dojo.ready` and jQuery's `$(document).ready` are tantamount to each other. However, I just ran into an issue with my application where in a function that was being called using `dojo.ready` was working fine for all browsers except for some versions of IE. I just happened to replace that with `$(document).ready` and it works across all browsers. I was happy to get it working but was not sure why it worked.

I did some basic search to find the difference between two but didn't find anything significant.

Comment: jQuery obviously supports more versions of IE. :)

Comment: Thanks powtac, but I was just curious to know how are the two different.

Comment: Sorry for my ironic answer. I don't know the difference. But jQuery is known to support a lot of browsers, also old IEs...

Comment: Just by curiosity, did you try the domReady plugin in 1.7 ? http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/domReady.html#dojo-domready

Comment: @Philippe - no, I didn't try that. Just looked at it and looks like a good one to use in such situations. Thanks much..

Answer (score 1):

Aside from any differences in how they determine if the document is ready. It is worth noting that dojo/ready integrates with other dojo infrastructure such as the parser and AMD loader, so that it can fire after all required widgets have been parsed, modules loaded, etc..

**Dojo < 1.7**

dojo.ready waits for dojo.require calls and the parser if parseOnLoad is true in your dojoConfig.

**Dojo >= 1.7**

dojo/ready waits for AMD requires, and additional functions can be queued. I believe requiring dojo/parser will cause it to queue the parsing operation.

dojo/domReady! AMD plugin provides the simple DOMContentLoaded type of functionality equivalent to jQuery(document).ready

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tests of ready implementations and the differences across JavaScript abstractions to handle cross-browser issues:

- [DOMContentLoaded Inconsistencies (in Browsers and JavaScript Libraries)](http://www.zachleat.com/web/domcontentloaded-inconsistencies/)
- [Are you ready for this?](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Are_you_ready_for_this)
- [window.onload problem](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/the-window-onload-problem-really-solved)
- [window.onload problem still](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/the-window-onload-problem-still)